# What are the ingredients used in this issen yoshoku video?

Tags: food-identification, japanese-cuisine

Hello everyone :) I'm looking for help to identify the ingredients that go into the preparation in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWRZUa2wAZE

This appears to be a type of okonomiyaki, however the recipe seems rather different from the ones I can find online. Below I will list the ingredients in order of appearance. Around 1:58 there is a cut in the video but they also show the okonomiyaki up close. I would be grateful if any of you could provide some assistance. :)

EDIT: This appears to be an unusual type of okonomiyaki known as issen yoshoku (壹錢洋食). Using this name I could find [this](https://hirakata46.com/post-6305) post, where they have a list of ingredients. However I'm not sure if/how they correspond to the ingredients in the video.

1. <strike>Okonomiyaki batter</strike> Batter: wheat flour and water (?)
2. Just on top of the batter: Katsuobushi (?)
3. Spring onions or maybe leek (?)
4. Eggs
5. White stuff: <strike>Some kind of cheese or</strike> maybe tempura scraps (tenkasu) (?)
6. Red stuff: Benishoga or sakura shrimp or both (?)
7. Black stuff: perhaps seasoned konnyaku (?)
8. White rings: perhaps kamaboko (?)
9. Meat
10. At the very end, I imagine okonomiyaki sauce or maybe .

Comment: I don't think those are okonmiyaki.  They look like crepes (which are also popular in Japan).  Look how they roll them up for serving; I've never seen that with okonomiyaki.  We have a couple Japanese members of SA, though, so hopefully they'll speak up.

Comment: You definitely cannot roll okonomiyaki.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It's been pointed out to me that this is called "issen yoshoku" and it's basically only made in one shop in Kyoto. See edit in the post. I'd still like help in identifying the ingredients.

Comment: by the colour and consistency when ladled and spread, then colour and crispness after cooking, it appears to be a type of Dosa batter, maybe made with rice flour. the sauce at the end looks like japanese gravy like served on Omurice.

Comment: this menu image might help: https://hirakata46.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/1561e66babb62d126d37586915a694c7.jpg

Comment: @GdD, the Japanese girl in this video making Hashimaki (Okonomiyaki roll) wouldn't agree: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G18sADTpIuA

Answer (score 1):

The dish is '''[issen yōshoku](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E9%8A%AD%E6%B4%8B%E9%A3%9F)''' (一銭洋食), literally "one-cent Western food", since a ''sen'' is one-hundredth of a yen.  The Japanese Wikipedia has a good article on this which is [fairly legible even in translation](https://ja-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E9%8A%AD%E6%B4%8B%E9%A3%9F?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp), but to summarize, it's basically a predecessor of okonomiyaki that dates back to the Taisho era days, when grilled wheat pancakes were still considered an exotic, Western food.

I can't speak to the ingredients in that video, and I'll admit the black stuff is a bit of mystery, but here's what a [typical Japanese recipe](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipe_cards/8e63edb8-e982-4904-8ab8-578b24f28e44) uses:

```
☆キャベツ　50g cabbage 
☆紅しょうが　適量 beni-shoga (red pickled ginger)
★水　120㏄ water
★小麦粉　50g flour
★片栗粉　小さじ2 katakuriko (potato starch)
★塩　小さじ1/4 salt
◇天かす　適量 tenkasu (deep-fried tempura bits, basically panko/breadcrumbs)
◇たまご　2個 egg
サラダ油　適量  vegetable oil
```